# CRON JOB in GOLANG

Tags: go

I AM USING IN CRON  PKG  https://github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron/blob/master/gocron.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/claudiu/gocron"
)

func task() {
    fmt.Println("I am runnning task.", time.Now())
}
func vijay() {
    fmt.Println("I am runnning vijay.", time.Now())
}

func main() {
    go test()

    gocron.Start()
    s := gocron.NewScheduler()
    gocron.Every(5).Seconds().Do(task)
    gocron.Every(10).Seconds().Do(vijay)

    <-s.Start()

}
func test() {
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
    gocron.Clear()
    fmt.Println("All task removed")
}
```

My problem is after removing all job, my program is still executing

i want to break the exection after removing all jobs

please help me out ,i am not able to find out how to do it ,
i tried to change the PKG source code also but not able to find out the way to do it

thank you all

Comment: It's only polite to link between your cross-posts so people don't waste their time: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/yayvQLhR4Bk

Comment: i am sorry sir ,i will keep this in mind

Answer (score 8):

First, you're creating a new scheduler, and waiting on it, but using the default scheduler to run your jobs.

Next, you're blocking on the channel returned by the `Start()` method. Close that channel to unblock the receive operation. This will also exit the main loop in the cron program if you aren't immediately exiting from `main`.

```
func main() {
    ch := gocron.Start()
    go test(ch)
    gocron.Every(5).Seconds().Do(task)
    gocron.Every(10).Seconds().Do(vijay)

    <-ch
}
func test(stop chan bool) {
    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
    gocron.Clear()
    fmt.Println("All task removed")
    close(stop)
}
```

which effectively is the same as

```
func main() {
    gocron.Start()
    gocron.Every(5).Seconds().Do(task)
    gocron.Every(10).Seconds().Do(vijay)

    time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)

    gocron.Clear()
    fmt.Println("All task removed")
}
```

If you're exiting immediately, it doesn't really matter if you call `Clear()` first and then stop the scheduler, you can simply exit the program.

Answer (score 2):

[JimB rights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34454176/1816872). But I don't know why do you use `gocron` methods and the `s` methods. This example works fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/claudiu/gocron"
)

func task() {
    fmt.Println("I am runnning task.", time.Now())
}
func vijay() {
    fmt.Println("I am runnning vijay.", time.Now())
}

func main() {
    s := gocron.NewScheduler()
    s.Every(2).Seconds().Do(task)
    s.Every(4).Seconds().Do(vijay)

    sc := s.Start() // keep the channel
    go test(s, sc)  // wait
    <-sc            // it will happens if the channel is closed
}
func test(s *gocron.Scheduler, sc chan bool) {
    time.Sleep(8 * time.Second)
    s.Clear()
    fmt.Println("All task removed")
    close(sc) // close the channel
}
```